# How to get all the values from form using React?

Tags: reactjs

I have set an initial state to store all of the values from my form. However, in order to tell the program that I'm targetting a checkbox I need to specify the type:

```
e.target.type === 'checkbox'
```

Even though it works I feel like I shouldn't need to specify the type in order to pull it's value. Can anyone tell me if this is the correct way to do it or if I'm missing something, please?

My STATE prints **username**, **lastname** and **accept** fields when interacting with the form, example:

```
{username: "Mike", lastname: "Brown", accept: true}
```

and here's a working [**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cuseim?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Findex.js):

Comment: question is if I have to specify e.target.type === 'checkbox' to target a field in my form? or if there's a generic way to do it? I feel like I shouldn't need to specify the type.

Comment: Do you need the data when the form submitted or when the input changes?

Comment: when the input changes

Comment: Hmm I can't found the way maybe you can create a component `Checkbox` to replace input with type checkbox and in the component you will still need to call the onChange props and instead of calling it with event you can just pass the checked value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a conditional in your handleChange, you can pass the value directly to the function like this:

```
const handleChange = (attribute, value) =>
  setInitialState((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [attribute]: value
  }));
```

And in your form use it like this:

```
return (
  <form>
    <input
      type="text"
      value={username}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange("name", e.target.value)}
    />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={accept}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange("accept", e.target.checked)}
    />
  </form>
);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: just what I needed brother! just to add my 2 cents here. I think it'll be better to pass the name like this handleChange(e.target.name, e.target.value). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can look at Formik and Yup. They can help you build forms with validation and they also integrate with UI libraries like Material UI.